# Trouble Drawing Circle in JS and moving them

Tags: javascript

today i've got a problem regarding JavaScript. 
I was given an exercise which consists on create a circle on the screen, using JavaScript, and then make it move to the right.
So the problem comes when i put in the function animate().
The code by itself works, it creates a circle, but when i insert the function animate() , put the code in it, and then try to recall it with requestFrameAnimation(animate), it just doesn't draw on the screen.
Code right down here. I've tried everything i am capable of, but couldn't fix it.
Thanks for the replies.

HTML:

```
<head>
<style type="text/css">
   canvas{
       border:1px solid black;


   }
   body{
   margin:0px;
      background-color:red;


   </style>




</head>


          <body>
            <canvas></canvas>
            <script src="canvas.js"></script>




            </script>

          </body>
```

JS:

```
 canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');       //CANVAS SELECTOR
      canvas.width = window.innerWidth;         //MATCHING THE CANVAS WIDTH WITH THE WINDOW WIDTH
       canvas.height = window.innerHeight;      //********************HEIGHT***************HEIGHT
       context=canvas.getContext("2d"); 




    var x=200;
  function animate(){                                      //Starting the function

     context.beginPath();                                  //Initializing a Path of drawings
     context.arc(x,200,100,0,Math.PI*2, true);               //drawing the circle
     context.fillStyle="rgba(120,10,200,0.5)";            //filling the circle
     context.fill();
     context.strokeStyle = 'blue';                         //giving the circle a strokeline
     context.stroke();
 x+=1;                                                    //increasing the circle x so that it keeps moving towards right
                   requestAnimationFrame(animate);        //calling back to the function so it keeps drawing infinitely.

  }
```

Comment: Is this the entire code? Because you aren't calling `animate` anywhere

Comment: created a quick codepen with initial `animate()` call: https://codepen.io/AndriusRimkus/pen/mzvOYz

Comment: Thank you, Andrius, forgot to call the animate at the end again